# Mapbox Studio Map doesn't match Mapbox in Xcode

Tags: mapbox

I have made a simple Mapbox map that includes all national borders but no country names.  You can see that map here:

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/rabbigarfinkel/cj4dipjb91i2l2snx81n7ka38.html?title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicmFiYmlnYXJmaW5rZWwiLCJhIjoiY2l2dnNuZWV0MDBiaDJ6cHNqNWx4MW00ZCJ9.KHHbkW5oQAXiwrh3w5xCqQ#0.4/0.002700/0.488694/0

But when I plug the map's Style URL into Interface Builder, the country names are all present.  I have hidden/deleted the relevant layers, and that is reflected correctly in the URL above.  But I always get the same map no matter what.

What should I do to get rid of the country names?

Thank you,

Eli

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that setting the maps styleURL in code rather than in Interface Builder solved my problem.